# UITableView manual scrolling to the last row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I have a table view controller which doesn't let me manually scroll to the last row. It automatically scrolls slightly up so I could never select the last 2-3 rows. Anyone experienced this problem? Should I set a minimum height for the table view to solve this? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer in the following post helped me fix this issue -

[-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:] scrolls, but goes back to 1st row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478931/uitableview-scrolltorowatindexpath-scrolls-but-goes-back-to-1st-row)

The initial CGSize for the UiTableView was set at a higher value (beyond the view bounds) and that was the issue. I upvoted that answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to scroll using touches to the last row? It may be a contentSize issue.

Comment: no i am unable to scroll using touches. how do i set contentSize?

Comment: i set a minimum height for the table view content size to 600. No change in the behavior.

Comment: if you're not manually setting contentSize, don't start now. Have you verified that the table's frame is correct, and what you expect? ie, if it's extending either offscreen or below another view, you'll get the behavior you describe above.

Answer (score 2):

Likely your tableView frame is too big and extends off the screen. This will prevent the bottom cells from being able to scroll up to the screen because they've reached the bottom of the tableView.

You will have to determine the visible area on your screen. But the code should look something like this:

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 324);
```

Here's the meanings of the CGRectMake values: (X, Y, Width, Height)

Comment: For a full screen tableview that accounts for variable screen sizes, use self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,320,320)style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Put whatever height as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set this [statusMessagesTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 80, 0)];